# When I use PyQt my embedded YouTube video won't show up

Tags: python, html, youtube-api

I am using PyCharm and used MacPorts to import PyQt4.  I got the HTML code from the Youtube API page.  I got the other half from this website: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Embedding%20Widgets%20in%20Web%20Pages.

The two code pieces put together:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

html = \
"""<iframe id="existing-iframe-example"
        width="640" height="360"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DjCO41GMiRg?enablejsapi=1"
        frameborder="0"
        style="border: solid 4px #37474F"
></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
  }
  function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
    var color;
    if (playerStatus == -1) {
      color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
    } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
      color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
    } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
      color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
    } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
      color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
    } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
      color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
    } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
      color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
    }
    if (color) {
      document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = color;
    }
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    changeBorderColor(event.data);
  }
</script>
"""

class WebWidget(QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
        painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawRect(self.width() / 4, self.height() / 4,
                         self.width() / 2, self.height() / 2)
        painter.end()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 100)

class WebPluginFactory(QWebPluginFactory):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWebPluginFactory.__init__(self, parent)

    def create(mimeType):
        if mimeType == "x-pyqt/widget":
            return WebWidget()

    def plugins(self):
        plugin = QWebPluginFactory.Plugin()
        plugin.name = "PyQt Widget"
        plugin.description = "An example Web plugin written with PyQt."
        mimeType = QWebPluginFactory.MimeType()
        mimeType.name = "x-pyqt/widget"
        mimeType.description = "PyQt widget"
        mimeType.fileExtensions = []
        plugin.mimeTypes = [mimeType]
        print("plugins")
        return [plugin]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    view = QWebView()
    factory = WebPluginFactory()
    view.page().setPluginFactory(factory)
    view.setHtml(html)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983148/the-sound-dont-stop-when-qwebview-window-closed-loaded-with-youtube-video) on how to load a YouTube video with `QWebView`. Try adding `view.load(QUrl("http://www.youtube.com/v/ID"))` in your `view = QWebView()`. You may also check this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846279/qt-or-pyqt4-how-can-i-pull-out-and-embed-only-the-box-of-youtube-clip). Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not work. I still see a black screen.

Answer (score -1):

## Switching from PyQt4 to PySide

I had this problem too, and I think I may have an answer. `PyQt4` is not the only option for Qt Application development in python, there is `PySide` as well.

---

You can install it through pip:

`pip install -U PySide`

---

or a package manager (if you use linux):

`sudo apt-get install python-pyside`

or for python3:

`sudo apt-get install python3-pyside`

---

After the installation is completed, replace the PyQt4 imports with this instead:

```
from PySide.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
```

Everything should look and function exactly the same and hopefully YouTube should work correctly.

Another bonus is that PySide has the `LGPL` license while PyQt4 has the `GPL` license so, when using PySide, you do not have to release the source code for your program.

Comment: I don't think "don't use that use this" is ever a great answer, and maybe is better served as just a comment on the original question